# How does the Service Bus "Send one or more messages" action work?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

The Service Bus connector for Logic apps has two modes for sending messages:

- [Send message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#send-message)
- [Send one or more messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#send-one-or-more-messages)

What is the difference between the two, and how do you use the latter to send more than one message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference, I could only distinguish the difference they send different number of messages and the parameter properties, one shows all properties you could use(not required) one you need to add manully.

As for how to send more than one message,  you could refer to the below pic. Choose `Add new item` and set the properties you want. I just test the message content.

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

Send array value to message :

One point the array value you want to send, you need point the value index in an array.  The expression would be like this `variables('messages')[1]`.

[image]

Two you want to send all values in array, you need use a for_each action to send them all.

[image]

Comment: Aha, I did try this, but I didn't make the mental connection that the '1' and '2' suffixes intend to refer to 'first message' and 'second message'. This to be honest seems fairly useless. I was hoping I would be able to supply an array, and have each item in the array be sent as a separate message, or something like that.

Comment: @Tom W, I updated the answer, you could have a try.

Comment: Thanks. I've concluded that this action is not useful and doesn't work the way I'd want. I would expect it to take an array of content parameters, and use the Topic/Queue batch capability to send a batch of messages derived from that input.

Comment: @TomW you could send multiple messages by providing one array. You would need to provide your data in the ContentData property. The array needs to look something like this:

[ { "ContentData": "value1" }, { "ContentData": "value2" } ]